# When should the constructor of the superclass be called from the subclass?

Tags: java, constructor, super

> The statement that calls the constructor of the superclass should be the last statement in the constructor of a subclass.

Is it a valid statement?

Comment: No. Should be first line.

Comment: it shud b fist i think ?

Comment: Well it must be first.

Comment: @ sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ would you please explain why?

Comment: Did you think to *try it and find out what happens*?

Comment: @Sunny Cause I'l finish the first stage of a game and then for next stage :)

Answer (score 4):

No, It should be the first statement of the sub class.

> Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the
>   subclass constructor.

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

No,that is not a valid statement.It **MUST** be the first statement of the child class's constructor.

If you don't add that line,the compiler will automatically add it.

### Example:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("Inside A's constructor.");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
       // super(); // THIS LINE WILL BE AUTOMATICALLY ADDED BY THE COMPILER.
       System.out.println("Inside B's constructor.");
       // super(); // THIS LINE WON'T COMPILE.
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it should be first statement...
Even though if the default constructor is absent in the first line of sub class constructor, the compiler implicitly calls the default constructor of its super class